# Problema con select encadenado con plugin formvalidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un select encadenado que se desabilita por orden jerarquico de los selects y no activa el submit, a menos que todos los select esten llenos.

Todo esta bien ahi, el problema surge cuando agrego el plugin de formvalidation, es mas un error estetico, debido a que quiero que marque error cuando un select este disabled, pero no lo hace, en caso de que llene los tres campos y quite el segundo select, como esta en orden jerarquico, deberia de marcar error con el tercer select, pero no lo hace.

Aqui esta el codigo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">jQuery Chained Select</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <form action="" id="addToCart">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Size</option>
            <option value="Small">Small</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
            <option value="X-Large">X-Large</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="color" id="color" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="qty" id="qty" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Quantity</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function chainSelect(current, target){
  var value1 = $(current).on('change', function(){
    if($(this).find(':selected').val() != '') {
      $(target).removeAttr('disabled');
      var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    } else {
      $(current).parent().nextAll().find('select, button').prop('disabled', 'disabled').val(null);
    }
  return value;
  });
  return value1;
}
size = chainSelect('#size', '#color');
color = chainSelect('#color', '#qty');
qty = chainSelect('#qty', '#submit');
$('#addToCart').submit(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Size: ' + size + '\nColor: ' + color + '\nQuantity: ' + qty);
});
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#addToCart')
             .formValidation({
                 excluded: ':disabled',
                 framework: 'bootstrap',
                 icon: {
                     valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                     invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                     validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                 },
                 fields: {
                    color: {
                         validators: {
                             notEmpty: {
                                 message: 'This field is required'
                             }
                         }
                     },
                     size: {
                         validators: {
                             notEmpty: {
                                 message: 'This field is required'
                             }
                         }
                     },
                                                              qty: {
                         validators: {
                             notEmpty: {
                                 message: 'This field is required'
                             }
                         }
                     }        
                 }
            })
});
```

[Aqui esta el enlace al codigo en codepen](http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/grJNzg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te hace falta añadir que antes de habilitar el `select` lo revalide, [este ejemplo](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-select/) es funcional en cada cambio

```
$('#addToCart').find('[name="color"]')
    .selectpicker()
    .change(function(e) {
        /* Revalidate the language when it is changed */
        $('#addToCart').formValidation('revalidateField', 'color');
    })
    .end()
    .formValidation({excluded: ':disabled', ... });
```

Con esto el comportamiento de tus `selects` deben ser como deseas, espero te sirva

Comment: Si funciono, muchas gracias, aqui dejo el codigo mas exacto, http://jsfiddle.net/guille1194/ab9b7abp/